# MySQL update column using group by

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to use group by clause to update the AVG column as follows:

```
UPDATE cratings r 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT race_id, runner_id, avg(final) AS avg FROM cratings GROUP BY race_id) u 
ON r.race_id = u.race_id and R.RUNNER_ID = U.RUNNER_ID 
SET r.AVG = u.AVG;
```

and all it seems to do is update the top row in the table?
Is there some way to update all rows in the table?

Thanks,

Comment: Hard to say without seeing sample data from the cratings table.  Just at a glance, it seems odd that you would group by race_id only, but the do a join on both race_id and runner_id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just join on `race_id`:

```
UPDATE cratings r JOIN
       (SELECT race_id, avg(final) AS avg
        FROM cratings
        GROUP BY race_id
       ) u 
       ON r.race_id = u.race_id 
    SET r.AVG = u.AVG;
```

Your use of `runner_id` in the `select` clause would not be accepted by (almost?) any other database than MySQL.  It confused you.  In fact, you should never put extra columns in the `select` of an aggregation query -- unless you really know what you are doing.  All columns in the `select` should either be in the `group by` or be arguments to aggregation functions (`sum()`, `min()`, `max()`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` clause in the inline view (subquery) only includes the `race_id` column. MySQL will return a value for `runner_id` in the SELECT list, but the value it returns will from an indeterminate row in the group.

The join predicate on the outer query references the `runner_id` column, so only the rows that have a matching `runner_id` are going to be updated.

I suspect you either want:

```
 ... GROUP BY race_id, runner_id ) u
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or, if you want an average for all runners in a given race, you want to *omit* the `runner_id` column from the SELECT list, and *omit* the join predicate on `runner_id`, a:

```
     (SELECT race_id, avg(final) AS avg FROM ...
  ON r.race_id = u.race_id
```